# Woocommerce Bookings Product Available Between Two Timestamps

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to see if a woocommerce booking timeslot is available bewteen two times. For example, I have a bookable product that is available 9:00am - 9:15am 12/27/17, when passing the unix timestamp for 9:00am 12/27/17 and 9:15am 12/27/17 i should receive true, else false.

I've tried wc_bookings_get_total_available_bookings_for_range, passing this function:

```
wc_bookings_get_total_available_bookings_for_range(wc_get_product($doc->ID), $time->getTimestamp(), $timeAhead->getTimestamp());
```

but it's always false. Which method should I use or why is it always false? I am not using resources as my product is a single professional.